# calculus textbook avoiding "nice" numbers: all numbers are decimals with 2 or 3 sig figs

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question

Many years ago, my father had a large number of older used textbooks.

I seem to remember a calculus textbook with a somewhat unusual feature, and I am wondering if the description rings a bell with anyone here.

Basically, this was a calculus textbook that took the slightly unusual route of avoiding "nice" numbers in all examples. The reader was supposed to always have a calculator at their side, and evaluate everything as a decimal, and only use 2 or 3 significant figures.

So for instance, rather than asking for the $\int_1^{\sqrt3} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, it might be from $x=1.2$ to $x=2.6$, say.

The author had done this as a deliberate choice, since most "real-life" math problems involve random-looking decimal numbers, and not very many significant digits.

Does this sound familiar to anybody? Any ideas what this textbook might have been?

Comment: ..why would you want this book? It would have you show results like $e^{3.14i} + 1 \approx 0$....

Answer (score 5):

Though this is probably not the book you are thinking of, *Calculus for the Practical Man* by Thompson does this. It is, most famously, the book that Richard Feynman learned calculus from, and was part of a whole series of math books "for the practical man". The reason I do not think it is the particular book you are thinking of is that the most recent edition was published in 1946, so there would be no mention of a calculator.

Comment: I don't see why the publication date of the book is a reason it isn't the right answer, since the exclusive use of 2 or 3 digit numbers in a calculus book is so strange there is probably just one such book! The idea that a calculator was needed for the book could simply reflect the experience of idmercer's father. Back in the 1950s or earlier readers would have had slide rules instead.

Comment: @KCd That's very true, I was assuming the instruction to "have a calculator at their side" came from the book.

Comment: The instruction to "have a calculator at your side" is not necessarily an exact quote from the book, and is just my vague memory of the intended approach.